# Is it guaranteed that asynchronus calls inside a for...of loop are going to be returned in order?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, asynchronous

Currently, I have a code that has to loop through an array and make an API request for each interation.

It looks something like this

```
let arrayOfIds = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21];
let order = []
let count = 0;

for (let id of arrayOfIds) {
  asyncAPICall(id)
    .then((result) => {
      order.push(count++);
    });
}
```

The question is *is it guranteed that `count++` pushed in the `order` array is **always** going to be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` (in correct ascending order)?*

I have tested several times and it is so, but I am not confident enough to use it in production.

I have also searched but I find mostly in other languages, and not directly answer my questions.

Thanks!

---

**Extra question:**

What should I do to make sure it's in order?

Comment: quick answer in general : no.

Comment: Async means asynchronous...

Comment: *asynchronous calls* means order is not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There is **NO** guarantee that your requests will be resolved in some strict order.

The reason why your code is working is that you're increasing `count` variable at the moment when your request is resolved. So in your case it's doesn't matter which request was resolved - the result will be the same (count++).

Instead of `order.push(count++);` try `console.log(result)`.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're sent in order, but they could response unordered as they are async.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee your promises run in order you could use Promise.all

I have rewritten your code accordingly with a little side effect that console logs the array value as it iterates through so you can see the running order in the console.

I created a new promise for your asyncAPICall to represent it. Note that the resolve argument is your return value from a successful promise.

The only gotcha with Promise.all is that if one of the promises fails, the whole chain will fail, there are ways around this, but thats a whole 'nother story'

```
let arrayOfIds = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21];
let order = []
let count = 0;

const asyncAPICall = (i) => new Promise ((resolve, fail) => {
    console.log("i am a new promise", i)
    resolve(order.push(count++))
})

const allPromises = arrayOfIds.map(arrayValue => asyncAPICall(arrayValue))
Promise.all(allPromises)
    .then((newArray) => console.log(newArray))
    .catch((e) => console.log('something has gone wrong', e))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all